# How to solve this lint warning "Implicit binary conversion from int to unsigned int"

Tags: c++, lint, misra, pc-lint

here is the code:

```
test.cpp

unsigned short x;
bool y;
if ((x==1)&& y)
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

I got a lint message:

```
Note 912 Implicit binary conversion from int
to unsigned int [MISRA Rule 48]
```

why? and how to avoid this?

Comment: `if ((x==1u)&& y)`, if that doesn't work you'll need to provide a complete example (which you should have done in the first place anyway).

Comment: Note this MISRA-C:1998 and this is C++.  Its fine in MISRA-C++:2008.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `x` which is `unsigned short` and `1` which is `int` by default. Hence you got your implicit binary conversion thing.

Give your compiler a hint that you actually want to compare `x` with another `unsigned` value:

`if ((x==1U) && y)`

Comment: This doesn't solve the warning, MISRA forbids implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ( ( static_cast<unsigned int>(1) == x ) && y)
```

Comment: get new error: Note 970 Use of modifier or type 'unsigned'
    outside of a typedef [MISRA Rule 13]

Comment: if ((unsigned short)(1)==x) && y) it works, thank you, but why?

Comment: Because somehow the static analysis tool here is complaining about "literal int to unsigned conversion" but not "C-style cast threw all of your type-safety out the window".

Comment: MISRA C++ 2008 forbids the use of C style casts (5-2-2, 5-2-7/8/9).  I am assuming MISRA C++ as @HeyJoy quotes MISRA rules.   MISRA C wouldn't complain.

Comment: @HeyJoy if ((unsigned short)(1)==x) && y) is not MISRA-compatible, it should not work. Both operands are implicitly promoted.

Answer (score 0):

because 1 is treated as int. Use

```
unsigned int x
```

or cast

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which version of MISRA you are using. You should be using MISRA-C++ when writing C++ code, everything else will be a violation of the MISRA rules. Compliance against MISRA-C++ can obviously not be checked with a MISRA-C checker.

Anyway, assuming you have a system with 32 bit integers, this should solve the problem no matter MISRA version:

```
if ( ( static_cast<uint32_t>(x) == 1u ) && y)   // compliant
```

The important part to understand is how implicit promotions work and how to avoid them:

- Casting the `1` literal to `unsigned short` will not solve anything. Such a cast is completely superfluous as the operand will get immediately integer promoted back to `int` anyway.

  `if ( ( x == static_cast<unsigned short>(1) ) && y)   // not compliant`

  `unsigned short ushort=1u; if ( ( x == ushort ) && y)   // not compliant`
- Casting the `1` literal to `unsigned int`or merely chaning it to `1u` (same thing) will make the program behave as expected, but it will not solve the MISRA warning. Because you still have an implicit type promotion of the `x` operand, which is the MISRA violation.

  `if ( ( x == 1u ) && y)   // not compliant`

  `if ( ( static_cast<unsigned int>(1) == x ) && y)   // not compliant`

Study *integer promotion* and *the usual arithmetic conversions*.